# Variables being affected by 'bad' instructions

Tags: c++

Below is my code, for solving problem 7 of PE ("find the 10001th prime"):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int n, int primes[], int l){
    int i=0;
    for (int i=0; i < l; i++){
        if (primes[i] != 0 && n%primes[i] == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    int k=3;
    int primes[10001] = {0};
    primes[0]=2;
    const int l=sizeof(primes)/sizeof(primes[0]);
    int N=0;
    while (N < l){
        if(isPrime(k, primes, l)==true){
            primes[++N]=k;
        }
        k+=2;
    }
    cout << primes[l-1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code solves the problem, but there is a mistake in it: on the final iteration of the `while` loop, the instruction is to set `primes[10001]=k;`, which attempts to change a value of an element of an array that doesn't exist. If I don't declare it to be constant, and (as a means of troubleshooting) replace `l` by `10001` in the while loop, the value of `l` becomes equal to the 10002th prime at the end of the loop.

Here is the main function part of this happening:

```
int main()
{
    int k=3;
    int primes[10001] = {0};
    primes[0]=2;
    int l=sizeof(primes)/sizeof(primes[0]);
    int N=0;
    while (N < l){
        if(isPrime(k, primes, 10001)==true){
            primes[++N]=k;
        }
        k+=2;
    }
    cout << l << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, why does this happen? I do know that a simple fix is to stop the loop at `l-1` (or better, initialize with `N=1` instead and increment `N` after), but I'm more interested in how this code can affect a variable that isn't being explicitly (directly?) involved in the bad part of the code.

Thank you!

Comment: `Which attempts to change a value of an element of an array that doesn't exist.`  You have a memory overwrote.  Once you do that, all bets are off as to what will happen.

Comment: Undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Comment: Out of curiousity though, at least roughly, what is happening in the background that would cause the program to write into `l` (rather than any other variable, or at all) when the element of the array doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` Operator does no bounds checking. `some_array[102]`, will simple go 102 * sizeof(type) if thats outside your array, thats outside your array. C++ won't care.

These are some of the nastiest bugs that can generated if you are lucky you program will crash, sometimes you can just end up changing somebody else's variable.

Which is why I harp on at work about using `std::array` and `std::vector` alot because they come with `.at(i)` functions which have bounds checking.

Comment: "If you are lucky...". And if you are unlucky, then some other, seemingly unrelated bug will occur elsewhere in the program, and you'll be spending long sleepless nights attempting to find the source of this bug.